# How do I garbage collect a Guix System generation?

Tags: guix, guixsd

Running `sudo guix gc --list-roots` on my Guix System I see a lot of system generations lying around, going all the way back to when I first installed the system.

```
$ sudo guix gc --list-roots
...
/var/guix/profiles/system-22-link
/var/guix/profiles/system-1-link
/var/guix/profiles/system-10-link
/var/guix/profiles/system-11-link
/var/guix/profiles/system-12-link
/var/guix/profiles/system-13-link
/var/guix/profiles/system-14-link
/var/guix/profiles/system-15-link
...
```

These are not garbage collected when I run `sudo guix gc --delete-generations=30d` as I would expect. Why is this and how do I GC the system roots?

Answer (score 4):

As I observed `guix gc` does not not touch any of the system gc-roots. There is a separate command `guix system delete-generations` for managing these. Running `guix system delete-generations 1m` followed by `guix gc` did remove system gc-roots older than one month and clean up the store in `/gnu/store` of the old state. On my machine this was a neat 34GiB.